# Correct way to prevent a systemd service from starting

Tags: linux, services, systemd

I'm trying to prevent systemd service `xrdp` from starting automatically on boot. So I tried `systemd disable xrdp`.

After reboot I found that the service is indeed disabled but also running. What is the correct way to prevent a systemd service from starting on boot? And what is `disable` supposed to be used for btw?

```
[root@myserver:~] # systemctl is-enabled xrdp
disabled
[root@myserver:~] 1 # systemctl status xrdp
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-08-03 12:19:19 CEST; 17s ago
     Docs: man:xrdp(8)
           man:xrdp.ini(5)
  Process: 1334 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1305 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1336 (xrdp)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
           └─1336 /usr/sbin/xrdp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One may set a service to not start automatically on startup, but it can still
be started by other services. You can show dependencies with:

```
systemctl list-dependencies xrdp
```

To disable a service completely you have to mask it:

```
sudo systemctl mask xrdp
```

It is likely that any service that needs to start xrdp will then throw an error.

Comment: There was another service xrdp-sesman that I had to disable.